# Android and Facebook SDK 3.0.1 function getUserID

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am implementing the new Facebook SDK 3.0.1 and I have some doubts about use with Session.

I created a function to query just the user id:

```
    String userID;
    public String getUserID(){
        final Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
            Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    if (session == Session.getActiveSession()) {
                        if (user != null) {
                            userID = user.getId();
                            System.out.println("User ID " + userID); //OK
                        }   
                    }   
                }
            }); 
            Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
            return userID;
        }else{
            return null;
        }

    }
```

The problem is when I do `System.out.println("ID is... "+FB.getUserID());` because only shows: "ID is...".

But the internal `println` perfectly shows the id (User ID XXXXXXXXX). **The problem is the time to receive the information. How I can I control it?**

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot control it. 
You are executing an async request that is a request that *"permits other processing to continue before the transmission has finished."* (see [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O)).
You have to wait until the `onCompleted` method is called by the request object.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a way around this. Simply use Request.executeAndWait(). that function does exactly what it sounds like it does, it pauses the thread until the onComplete is finished.